# Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined whilst testing httpclient call

Tags: angular, unit-testing, ionic-framework, karma-jasmine, ionic4

I am trying to unit test some my code in an ionic4 app the code, calls an endpoint and maps the reponse to an object it also adds a tap, so that I can return this.faults as an observable from my dataservice.

```
fetchFaults(): Observable<Fault[]>
{
return this.http.get<{data: Fault[]}>('https://server/api/faults')
  .pipe(tap((data) => this.faults = data.data) // cache
      , map((data) => data.data)); // return just Fault[] from data.data to the subscriber
}
```

Which I am trying to test with

```
  describe('fetchFaults', () => {
    it('makes expected calls', () => {
      const httpClientStub: HttpClient = TestBed.get(HttpClient);
      spyOn(httpClientStub, 'get');
      service.fetchFaults();
      expect(httpClientStub.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
```

but I am getting the error Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined do I need to return anything from the httpstub?

Comment: Why not use the HttpClientTestingModule? But your test fails because your spy doesn't return anything, hence the error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the correct way to write a unit test against your service.

```
import { TestBed, fakeAsync, tick, getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';

import { FaultService, Fault } from './fault.service';

describe('Program Service Tests', () => {
    let injector: TestBed;
    let service: FaultService;
    let httpMock: HttpTestingController;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
            providers: [
                FaultService
            ]
        });

        injector = getTestBed();
        service = injector.get(FaultService);
        httpMock = injector.get(HttpTestingController);
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        httpMock.verify();
    });

    it('should get the faults', fakeAsync(() => {
        const results = {data: []};

        service.fetchFaults().subscribe(_ => expect(results.data).toBe(_));

        const req = httpMock.expectOne((request: HttpRequest<any>): boolean => {
            expect(request.url).toEqual('https://server/api/faults');
            expect(request.method).toBe('GET');
            return true;
        });
        req.flush(results);
        tick();
    }));
});
```

---

The reason you are getting that error is that you need to tell the spy to call through to the original implementation. You can do that by chaining `.and.callThrough()`. A better and more thorough testing implementation is the code I included above though.

Comment: Thanks again, it was actually your answer from lastnight that I was trying to test! I feel like a kid getting his dad to do his homework. Thank you very much!

Comment: @JaChNo - No problem and glad to help!